# Dart Substring from a Link/URL

Tags: string, dart, split

I am trying to get `26189-abstract-color-background.jpg` from this string

```
void main() {
  //? link string
  String s = "http://www.exampleSite.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg?666ff";
  // s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
  String s1 = s.substring(s.indexOf('') - 2);
  print(s1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Uri.parse()` and `pathSegments`

```
 void main() {
  String s = "http://www.exampleSite.com/files/146/26189-abstract-color-background.jpg?666ff";
  var uri = Uri.parse(s);
  print(uri.pathSegments.last);
}
```